# Changing the vim color scheme only highlights lines of text?

Tags: command-line, colorscheme, microsoft-windows

I'm a big noob to vim here. I was trying to change the colorscheme of vim by editing the `.vimrc` file, but as I was playing around with different color schemes ([ayu](https://github.com/ayu-theme/ayu-vim) and [gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/), for example) I noticed that only the lines that have actual text on them get highlighted, everything else stays the same black command line background color as before (see screenshots below).

I am assuming this has something to do with the fact that I am using the Windows command line and am SSH'ing to a remote Linux machine, but I have no idea how to have vim change the *entire* background instead of just where the text is. Does anyone know what to do/if it is possible to get the whole background highlighted?

Thanks so much!
[image: An example of the strange highlighting]
[image: The .vimrc file with the strange highlighting]

Comment: This can sometimes results from drawing errors or misconfigured terms (or misconfigured colorschemes). Check $TERM (env var), t_Co (vim option set based on TERM), and try doing a `:redraw`

Comment: Thanks! Your comment lead me to checking if it was an issue with `screen` not supporting 256 colors, and so I added the line `term "screen-256color"` to my `/etc/.screenvrc` file, and that solved the problem! (however, it did create a new problem in that now if I add the line `set termguicolors` to my `.vimrc` file it just changes all text to white... which means I can't use themes that rely on the `termgui` option like ayu). But at least some custom themes work now!

Comment: If you want to put the stuff that fixed it for me (adding `term "screen-256color"` to my `/etc/.screenvrc` file) in an answer, I'll accept your answer! If you also want to help troubleshoot why `set termguicolors` now turns everything white when it didn't before I would **love** the help, but no pressure at all if you just want the Reputation now.

Comment: ill write the answer a bit later; as for the termguicolors, well, 256-color terms dont support truecolor (i think it’s 20-bit color? Much more than 256). If you really want termguicolors, you need a term that supports it (afaik tmux/screen do not), or use gvim. I happily live with 256 colors bc i do everything in tmux.

Comment: Oh, okay, perfect. Well I'll live with 256 colors as well instead of truecolor. It looks like according [this forum chain I found](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1425567) there is a way to get screen to support truecolor, but it's a pretty janky process to get there and I tried a little bit of what they said but it didn't immediately work and I don't want to dump a bunch of time into trying to support that. Thanks for helping me get 256 colors working!

Comment: Glad to see your problem got solved; did some more research, looks like screen and tmux do support truecolor (of course, only if the underlying terminal does too) :)

Comment: Looks like a problem with BCE. Does `:let &t_ut=''` fix it? See http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html

Comment: For the record, *tmux* supports true-color (24-bit) since v2.2, and *screen* has support on its master branch. [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728#terminal-multiplexers) is a terrific reference for true-color support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can sometimes results from drawing errors or misconfigured terms (or misconfigured colorschemes).

A good diagnostic checklist is:

1. Check the environment variable `$TERM`
2. Check the vim option `'t_Co'` (it is usually set based on `$TERM` and should not need changed)
3. and try doing a `:redraw`

Often, if the values are misaligned (or smaller than expected), colorschemes won't be able to use their full range of values (256 or truecolor/20-bit, depending).

#### Screen

By default, the `$TERM=screen` that screen uses is not 256-color. One can fix this with:

```
# /etc/.screenrc (or ~/.screenrc)
screen-256color
```

However, this is only 256 color support (the same amount the typical `xterm-256color` supports). If your terminal (like iTerm2, for example) supports truecolor, then you should [use the `--truecolor` option to screen](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1425567). Then you can use `termguicolors`.

#### Tmux

By default, the `$TERM=screen` that tmux uses is not 256-color. One can fix this with:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

`xterm-256color` may work as well (untested).

Finally, this is again 256 color. If you want truecolor (and `termguicolors`) support, you'll need to [set the overrides correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783367/tmux-tmux-true-color-is-not-working-properly) (apparently this can be tricky to get right).

If often goes something like:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
# OLDTERM=TERM from outside of tmux
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",$OLDTERM*:Tc"
```

Make sure to restart tmux.