# Ugly black thing when using :ls with colorscheme

Tags: colorscheme

I installed gruvbox color-scheme. Then I did :ls and saw this:
[image]

After ".vimrc" there's some black stuff. It is kind of ugly and makes it harder to read. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does a `:redraw!` fix it?

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble No, it doesn't. If I :redraw! , then when I :ls again, same thing happens

Comment: I've a hunch, it's a terminal emulator problem. Try out a different terminal emulator please and report back, would you? And if you're using gvim, then you should use `set termguicolors`, although you could use termguicolors even in terminal vim if your terminal emulator is up for it. Overall, check if the problem persists with other terminal emulators and post your vimrc and also the colorscheme.

Comment: Yes: the black appears to be artifacts from the screen drawing, and the second redraw is necessary to fix it. Im not sure of a way to avoid it being necessary every time though.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/17691/10604 this qa of mine might be relevant

Comment: @EnanAjmain I'm using vim on debian with mate terminal. Now I tried gnome-terminal and same thing happens. However then I tried xterm, and it hasn't that issue

Comment: I found how to solve it: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9774/problem-with-colorscheme

Comment: It's supposed to be fixed. Did you try termguicolors? It was introduced for 256 color terminals. Whatever, glad you could solve it.